# Can't interrupt/terminate Ruby script with Ctrl+C on Windows

Tags: ruby, interrupt, terminate

My script opens TCP connection and reads data from server. If server does not respond I try to interrupt the script with Ctrl+C, but it does not work. The only way to terminate the script is to kill process in task manager. Any ideas how to interrupt such script?

```
require 'socket'

host = '...'
port = ...

s = TCPSocket.open(host, port)

while line = s.gets
  puts line.chop
end

s.close
```

Answer (score 1):

trap("SIGINT") { clean up; exit}

Comment: This would handle the signal generated by Ctrl+C. My problem is that this signal is not generated while code is waiting on s.gets.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed, that it I cick Ctrl+C while waiting response from server, and some time latter response comes, the application terminates. But while I wait on socket (s.gets), the Ctrl+C has no effect.

So I solved the problem by running network code in a different thread.

```
require 'socket'

host = '...'
port = ...

t = Thread.new do
  s = TCPSocket.open(host, port)

  while line = s.gets
    puts line.chop
  end

  s.close 
end

STDIN.getc
```

Now I can terminate script by typing any character. But still would be nice to know about alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, type Ctrl+Pause